# How to render the same partial multiple times in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, partial-views

I am trying to render the same partial view multiple times, but it only renders the last partial in this set.  What am I missing to render each one?

```
<ul class="hours">
    <%=
        Time.use_zone(@place.timezone) do
            render partial: 'places/place_hours', locals: { :timezone => @place.timezone, :open => @place.monday_open, :close => @place.monday_close, :day => 'Monday', :is_today => Time.now.in_time_zone.monday? }
            render partial: 'places/place_hours', locals: { :timezone => @place.timezone, :open => @place.tuesday_open, :close => @place.tuesday_close, :day => 'Tuesday', :is_today => Time.now.in_time_zone.tuesday? }
            render partial: 'places/place_hours', locals: { :timezone => @place.timezone, :open => @place.wednesday_open, :close => @place.wednesday_close, :day => 'Wednesday', :is_today => Time.now.in_time_zone.wednesday? }
            render partial: 'places/place_hours', locals: { :timezone => @place.timezone, :open => @place.thursday_open, :close => @place.thursday_close, :day => 'Thursday', :is_today => Time.now.in_time_zone.thursday? }
            render partial: 'places/place_hours', locals: { :timezone => @place.timezone, :open => @place.friday_open, :close => @place.friday_close, :day => 'Friday', :is_today => Time.now.in_time_zone.friday? }
            render partial: 'places/place_hours', locals: { :timezone => @place.timezone, :open => @place.saturday_open, :close => @place.saturday_close, :day => 'Saturday', :is_today => Time.now.in_time_zone.saturday? }
            render partial: 'places/place_hours', locals: { :timezone => @place.timezone, :open => @place.sunday_open, :close => @place.sunday_close, :day => 'Sunday', :is_today => Time.now.in_time_zone.sunday? }
        end
    %>
</ul>
```

**Result:**

Sunday: Closed

**Expected:**

Monday: Open 10:00am - 7:00pm

Tuesday: Open 10:00am - 7:00pm

Wednesday: Open 10:00am - 7:00pm

Thursday: Open 10:00am - 7:00pm

Friday: Open 10:00am - 7:00pm

Saturday: Open 10:00am - 7:00pm

Sunday: Closed

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with a work around, but still curious if the question has an answer.

```
<ul class="hours">
  <%=
      place_vars = [
              { :timezone => @place.timezone, :open => @place.monday_open, :close => @place.monday_close, :day => 'Monday', :is_today => Time.now.in_time_zone.monday? },
              { :timezone => @place.timezone, :open => @place.tuesday_open, :close => @place.tuesday_close, :day => 'Tuesday', :is_today => Time.now.in_time_zone.tuesday? },
              { :timezone => @place.timezone, :open => @place.wednesday_open, :close => @place.wednesday_close, :day => 'Wednesday', :is_today => Time.now.in_time_zone.wednesday? },
              { :timezone => @place.timezone, :open => @place.thursday_open, :close => @place.thursday_close, :day => 'Thursday', :is_today => Time.now.in_time_zone.thursday? },
              { :timezone => @place.timezone, :open => @place.friday_open, :close => @place.friday_close, :day => 'Friday', :is_today => Time.now.in_time_zone.friday? },
              { :timezone => @place.timezone, :open => @place.saturday_open, :close => @place.saturday_close, :day => 'Saturday', :is_today => Time.now.in_time_zone.saturday? },
              { :timezone => @place.timezone, :open => @place.sunday_open, :close => @place.sunday_close, :day => 'Sunday', :is_today => Time.now.in_time_zone.sunday? }
      ]
      Time.use_zone(@place.timezone) do
        render partial: 'places/place_hours', locals: { :place_vars => place_vars }
      end
  %>
</ul>
```

Then each loop through the partial for displaying the content.